# Punctuation after "Half of the time"

Tags: punctuation

"Half of the time I was working from about eight in the morning until eight at night, and the other half I was incapacitated by excruciating pain."

This is what I have currently. Is this correct or is there a better way to approach this sentence? To be specific, I am wondering about my comma usage, and whether or not more commas should be added, however, all tips are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: I'd replace the one after _however_ with a semicolon. I'd consider a comma optional in "Half of the time, I was working from about eight in the morning until eight at night." But I'd consider "Half of the time, I was working from about eight in the morning until eight at night, and the other half, I was incapacitated by excruciating pain." unwieldy: I'd stick with your version. Certainly, just adding one extra comma after _morning_ gives a lopsided result.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence:

> "Half of the time I was working from about eight in the morning until
>   eight at night, and the other half I was incapacitated by excruciating
>   pain."

No other commas are necessary: in speaking your sentence, I wouldn't pause after "Half of the time" or after "the other half".

That said, you might want to consider separating the independent clauses by a semicolon rather than the conjunction *and*:

> "Half of the time I was working from about eight in the morning until
>   eight at night; the other half I was incapacitated by excruciating
>   pain."

According to Strunk and White, *The Elements of Style* (Third Edition, Macmillan, 1979):

> "If two or more clauses grammatically complete and not joined by a
>   conjunction are to form a single compound sentence, the proper mark
>   of pronunciation is a semicolon."

A semicolon is preferable to a period in this case because of the close relationship between the two statements, their being linked by first *the one half* and then *the other half*.